# how to query for phrases(shingles) in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following string "Word1 Word2 StopWord1 StopWord2 Word3 Word4".
When I query for this string using ["bool"]["must"]["match"], I would like to return all text that matches "Word1Word2" and/or "Word3Word4".

I have created an analyzer that I would like to use for indexing and searching.
Using analyze API, I have confirmed that indexing is being done correctly. The shingles returned are "Word1Word2" and "Word3Word4"

I want to query so that text matching "Word1Word2" and/or "Word3Word4" are returned. How can I do this dynamically - meaning, I don't know up front how many shingles will be generated, so I don't know how many match_phrase to code up in a query.

```
"should":[
       { "match_phrase" : {"content": phrases[0]}},
       { "match_phrase" : {"content": phrases[1]}}
 ]
```

Comment: I tried to query match_phrase but I don't get any hits.

Comment: Could you please share your mapping info? That'd be helpful

Comment: "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "my_join_field": { 
            "type": "join",
            "relations": {
              "document": "page" 
            }
          }   
        }
  }

Comment: I have used analyze API to confirm that the shingles returned are "Word1Word2" and "Word3Word4". What I need is a way to query so that text matching either of these shingles. The only thing I can think of is to do an analyze, grep token, and then create a bool should query with the two shingles.

Comment: i have a query string "green eggs ham", and a document containing the text "green eggs"

Elasticsearch analyzes the query string and creates the following phrases(shingles), 
"green eggs"
"eggs ham"

but when I do a match_phrase on the entire query string, I don't get any hits.
i understand that's because the entire "phrase" should match the text.

i need a way to get back text matching any of the phrases in the query string.
Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To query for shingles(and unigrams), you could set up your mappings to handle them cleanly in separate fields. In the example below, the field "shingles" will be used to analyze and retrieve shingles, while the implicit field will be used to handle unigrams.

```
PUT /my_index
 {
  "settings": {
     "number_of_shards": 1,
     "analysis": {
        "filter": {
           "my_shingle_filter": {
              "type": "shingle",
              "min_shingle_size": 2,
              "max_shingle_size": 2,
              "output_unigrams": false
           }
        },
        "analyzer": {
           "my_shingle_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard",
              "filter": [
                 "lowercase",
                 "my_shingle_filter"
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
}

PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
   "my_type": {
      "properties": {
         "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
               "shingles": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "match": {
                "title": "<your query string>"
            }
         },
         "should": {
            "match": {
               "title.shingles": "<your query string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Ref. Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide....